# How can I translate error messages from Python core if used within wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a wxPython based application, where all my own strings are translated via gettext. Now I would like to use native Python error messages, for example in file handling operations.

Q1: How can I translate an error message that comes from Python core ? Are those messages generally translateable, I mean as a totally separate job ?

Q2: Is there a chance from the native error mechanism to suggest something (a string) that can be used as wx's window title ? (this one also translateable, if possible)

(Q3: Rely on native error message in this case is a good or a bad idea ?)

For example this version:

```
# (not shown here) try opening a file;
# (not shown here) return immediately if ok;
# if not ok:
except IOError:
  dlg = wx.MessageDialog(None, (_("Could not read the file\n%s") % filename_wpath), _("File operation error"), wx.OK | wx.ICON_ERROR)
  result = dlg.ShowModal()
  # etc.

# have no idea if this message covers all possible IOError types
```

versus this version:

```
# (not shown here) try opening a file;
# (not shown here) return immediately if ok;
# if not ok:
except IOError, e:
  dlg = wx.MessageDialog(None, str(e), _("File operation error"), wx.OK | wx.ICON_ERROR)
  result = dlg.ShowModal()
  # etc.

# example of e error message:
# [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'D:\\Documents\\Testapp\\Testfile.txt'
```